# Call to a member function getFrontend() on boolean in Infortis/Brands/Block/AbstractBlock.php

Tags: magento2

im getting this error on product view page and was wondering if you could help me with this:

```
    Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getFrontend() on boolean in /home/applian1/public_html/app/code/Infortis/Brands/Block/AbstractBlock.php:161 Stack trace: #0 /home/applian1/public_html/app/code/Infortis/Brands/Block/Logo.php(116): Infortis\Brands\Block\AbstractBlock->getBrand(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor)) #1 /home/applian1/public_html/app/code/Infortis/Brands/Block/Logo.php(103): Infortis\Brands\Block\Logo->getCurrentBrand() #2 /home/applian1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(1035): Infortis\Brands\Block\Logo->getCacheKeyInfo() #3 /home/applian1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(1093): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->getCacheKey() #4 /home/applian1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(660): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache() #5 /home/applian1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(558): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock-> in /home/applian1/public_html/app/code/Infortis/Brands/Block/AbstractBlock.php on line 161
```

Answer (score 1):

The Block is calling an attribute that doesn't exist anymore. I think in this particular case the Brands extension in Infortis is calling an attribute (by default "manufacturer"). You can check to see if that attribute was not deleted by mistake. If yes, you can recreate the attribute with the same name "manufacturer" and it will solve the problem.

BTW, The problem happens only when the cache block is enabled.